# How to open Terminal at last open directory?

Tags: terminal, osx-lion

Every time I open my Terminal application at work it starts from a clean slate (e.g. it opens from the ~/ directory). But at home on my laptop my Terminal always remembers the last directory I was in (and all the commands on the screen) and displays them to me.

I'm trying to get this to happen when I'm at work but I can't find any information on it (I've no idea why or how my laptop managed to set itself to work that way?).

The only thing I've found out is that I can change the preferences so the Terminal executes a particular command when the app is started up, but that's not quite what I want (simply because I'm not sure what command I would run to get the Terminal to go to the directory I was looking at when I had the Terminal open last).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're using Lion, it should do that automatically.

You might have disabled the Resume functionality systemwide or in Terminal.

Make sure it's enabled systemwide. You can also try to manually enable it for Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.Terminal NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool true
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this worked for me. But my colleague on Snow Leopard has the same issue and I was hoping that command would work for him but it didn't? Any ideas why that might not work for Snow Leopard?

Comment: Because “Resume” is a feature introduced in Lion (10.7).